# Беспорядок в метках, связанных с .NET

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Вот метки, связанные с .NET (отсортированы по количеству вопросов):

- [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net)
- [.net-5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5)
- [.net-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-6)
- [.net-4.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0)
- [.net-4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8)
- [.net-4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5)
- [.net-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-7)
- [.net4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4)
- [.net4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4.5)

Я, конечно, не знаток в .NET, но по-моему их тут многовато.

Как минимум, надо объединить [.net-4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5) с [.net4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4.5).

Comment: Ну и что? У C++'а тоже разные метки на разные редакции, но это не повод что-то с ними делать. Хотя насчёт `.net-4.5` и `.net4.5` согласен. ЗЫ: только что посмотрел метку `.net-4.5`, они уже объеденины.

Comment: @ΝNL993 с 4 и 4.0 то же самое, кто-то оперативно слил синонимизировал)

Comment: Обычная практика для меток с кучей различных версий - одна метка общая, и по одной на каждую значимую версию. .net4 - .net-4.0 и .net4.5 - .net-4.5 действительно стоит объединить (или удалить нестандартно-оформленные).

Comment: @insolor с `4` и `4.0` не уверен, что надо объединять. Т.к. `4` я бы скорее интерпретировал как `4.x`, а не `4.0`. Но вообще они синонимизованы уже как 8 лет почти - с "10 июн 2015".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Здесь нет (почти) никаких проблем. Версионные метки - это нормально. Есть даже [некоторые идеи](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/339911), что подобные ситуации должны покрываться каким-то деревом зависимостей меток. Но эта идея пока находится лишь на уровне идеи и шагов к какой-либо реализации на SO, насколько я знаю, не предвидится.

В упомянутых метках есть одна проблема. Но эта проблема существует уже с 2015 года, и вероятно, уже де-факто проблемой не является. Речь о метках [.net4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4) и [.net-4.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0). Они [являются синонимами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-4.0/synonyms). Однако, в моём понимании `4` - это `4.x`, т.е. любая минорная версия для мажорной `4`. Это и `4.0` и `4.2.100500` и `4.9999` и т.п. Но так как это уже реально старая версия, оно никому не мешает, последний вопрос, заданный с этой меткой, был "1 ноя 2019".

Рассинонимизировать, конечно, ничего здесь не надо. Но в будущем на подобные схемы синонимизации надо смотреть чуть повнимательнее.

Метки [.net4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4.5) и [.net-4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5) также уже объединены ещё в 2015 году!